# Neo4j: second merge for relationship not working properly

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working with email data.  I have 2 outcomes in the field `Outcome2` and they are `FAILED_TO` and `TO`. The first one `FAILED_TO` works fine if there is a failed to event the nodes are created and all properties, are updated or added.  But the `TO` portion doesnt work.  No new nodes are created.  Now this was created later on in the statement.  This may be a simple fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  And I would like to avoid apoc if at all possible.

```
// NO ATTACHMENT OR LINK - FOLLOWING IMPORTS
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/new_neo_test_3.csv") AS row
WITH row, datetime(row.DateTime) AS dt
MERGE (a:Sender {name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld})
ON CREATE SET a.firstseen = dt
SET a.lastseen = dt
MERGE (b:Recipient {name: row.To})
ON CREATE SET b.firstseen = dt
SET b.lastseen = dt
WITH a, b, row, dt
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false" AND row.Outcome2 = "FAILED_TO"
MERGE (a)-[rel1:FAILED_TO]->(b)
ON CREATE SET rel1.firstseen = dt
SET rel1.lastseen = dt
SET rel1.timesseen = coalesce(rel1.timesseen, 0) + 1
WITH a,b,row,dt,rel1
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false" AND row.Outcome2 = "TO"
MERGE (a)-[rel2:TO]->(b)
ON CREATE SET rel2.firstseen = dt
SET rel2.lastseen = dt
SET rel2.timesseen = coalesce(rel2.timesseen, 0) + 1
return a,b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of these two lines

```
WITH a, b, row, dt
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false" AND row.Outcome2 = "FAILED_TO"
```

The `WHERE ... AND row.Outcome2 = "FAILED_TO` literally removes the other rows where `row.Outcome2 = "TO"`.

Instead, you can do something like the following. Instead of the `WHERE row.outcome2`, create a collection of `[1]` for each case when either `FAILED_TO` or `TO` are found.  Then later, use that in a `FOREACH` loop to create that relationship if the corresponding collection has a value.

Since `roe.Woutcome2` can only be one value or the other only one of the sets of statement inside the `FOREACH` clause will actually be executed per row.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/new_neo_test_3.csv") AS row
WITH row, datetime(row.DateTime) AS dt
MERGE (a:Sender {name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld})
ON CREATE SET a.firstseen = dt
SET a.lastseen = dt
MERGE (b:Recipient {name: row.To})
ON CREATE SET b.firstseen = dt
SET b.lastseen = dt
WITH a, b, row, dt 
, CASE WHEN row.Outcome2 = 'FAILED_TO' THEN [1] ELSE [] END AS fail
, CASE WHEN row.Outcome2 = 'TO' THEN [1] ELSE [] END AS success
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false"
FOREACH ( x in fail | 
  MERGE (a)-[rel1:FAILED_TO]->(b)
    ON CREATE SET rel1.firstseen = dt
  SET rel1.lastseen = dt
  SET rel1.timesseen = coalesce(rel1.timesseen, 0) + 1
)
FOREACH ( x in success | 
  MERGE (a)-[rel2:TO]->(b)
    ON CREATE SET rel2.firstseen = dt
  SET rel2.lastseen = dt
  SET rel2.timesseen = coalesce(rel2.timesseen, 0) + 1
)
RETURN a, b
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, and works for my use case.  You don't know how many ways if have tried to get this to work.  Thank you. @Dave Bennett